# File(Size more than 2 gb) Uploaded with associated record For `Site Guest User` in Salesfore

Tags: site.com

I was stuck with a very strange issue.
Can anyone suggest me what to do, the scenario is:
I want to allow my `site user` to create record and along with that the user can upload the file(can be greater than 2 gb). File should be associated with that particular record in salesforce.
Can anyone help me out in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [File Size Limits in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_size_limits.htm&language=nl) you can't have a file > 2GB. Even getting close to 2GB is going to be an issue. See [Upload files upto 2GB from Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24941/upload-files-upto-2gb-from-apex)

Comment: Hi Daniel,thanks for reply.Yes the question is quite similar but my requirement is something different.Actually i want my site guest user to create the record after which they can be able to upload files with that .it can be greater than 2 gb.is their any feasible way to do this through salesforce.else I need to move to some other platform for achieving this functionality and save the uploaded file link to the particular record.Please suggest.

Comment: If you want files approaching 2GB or larger I'd suggest going with an external platform and then linking to the record from Salesforce. Anything over 10MB starts to become a special case to support.

Comment: You can't be able to upload that much size of file in salesforce , due to salesforce storage limit. In order to do so you need to use 3rd party storage server for saving the file.Also you need to use some server level language (such as java,.net,python etc)and make the handler class(for handling the request from salesforce) as a web hook for uploading the file to storage server and hit your request to that hook from salesforce (vf page) for uploading/downloading request.

Comment: Thanks @AnchalGarg for your comment.I understand that in order to achieve this functionality I need to depend on 3rd party storage and would have to handle the request from salesforce using java,.net.That would require a good R&D from our side to make this functionality in working state.Can you please suggest any workaround or pre-built code that is somewhat following the same concept.can you point me out on the right direction on this scenario.

Comment: Cloud Drop is One such App that is some what following the somewhat same logic in order to store any number and size of files that can be associated with any salesforce object with Rackspace server. Please check the following link for more information:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IzEDEA0

http://mansasys.com/clouddrop

Thanks

Anchal Garg